# using Windows.UI.Popups

Tags: visual-studio, c#-4.0

I am trying to make a WPF app for school. it's very simple, just needs to take users name as input and when the ok button is clicked a dialog box comes up saying Hi (your name). I've only ever done console applications before so I'm having trouble figuring out the WPF stuff. my books says to use Windows.UI.Popups and then write the code MessageDialog msg = new MessageDialog ("Hello " + username.Text); then put msg.ShowAsync ();

the problem is it just keeps saying UI is not a namespace? what am I missing?

Comment: What operating system are you using? You will need Visual Studio 2015 and Windows 10 in order to make this work in a desktop application.

Comment: that's what I am using. Eventually I used MessageBox.Show, but I would still like to know how to use the other way as well.

Comment: Can't say for sure what the problem is, then, without seeing your screen. I don't have VS 2015 in front of me to try creating a WPF app for test purposes. Do make sure that you've added a reference to the Windows.winmd assembly. And that you have explicitly indicated that your app is designed for/supports Windows 10. I'm not sure if that is the default for new C# applications. (You have tagged the question C# 4.0, which is sort of strange if you're using VS 2015. It uses C# 6.0 by default, IIRC.)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but someone might bump into it like i did.

The reason you are getting the error is because the Windows.UI.Popups is UWP related library and is not available in WPF applications.

Here is the Microsoft reference document for MessageDialog Class
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.popups.messagedialog?view=winrt-19041

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using WPF, you will have to [`MessageBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messagebox?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Example code adapted from the above page:

```
string message = "You clicked OK.";
string caption = "OK";
_ = MessageBox.Show(message, caption, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
```